# An exception occurred while polling the repository

Tags: svn, azure-pipelines

I use a private build agent to access an on premise Subversion source control. I created a build pipeline which works. I want to configure continuous integration, so I enable the trigger with a polling interval 180s and configure the path. This resulted in the following build error

> An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException:
>   Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://myPrivateServer:5000/svn/CCE/trunk/myProjecte' --->
>   SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://myPrivateServer:5000/svn/CCE/trunk/myProjecte' --->
>   SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: No such host is known. --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client,
>   SvnException error, Object targets) at
>   SharpSvn.SvnClient.Info(SvnTarget target, SvnInfoArgs args,
>   EventHandler`1 infoHandler) at SharpSvn.SvnClient.GetInfo(SvnTarget
>   target, SvnInfoEventArgs& info) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnConnector.GetInfo(Uri
>   repositoryUri, String sourceBranch, ExternalConnection connection,
>   Int32 timeoutSeconds, Int64& lastChangeRevision) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1\_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnConnector.cs:line
>   45 at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnConnector.GetLogs(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, Uri repositoryUri, String sourceBranch, Int64
>   lastVersionBuilt, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds,
>   IEnumerable`1& logItems) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnConnector.cs:line
>   73 at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass23_3.b__3()
>   in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnSourceProvider.cs:line
>   583 at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpRetryHelper.Invoke(Action
>   action, Int32& remainingRetries) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Vssf\Client\WebApi\HttpRetryHelper.cs:line 51 at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnConnector.RetrySvnAction(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, Action action, Int32 retryLimit, Int32& retries) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnConnector.cs:line
>   197 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnConnector.RetrySvnAction(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, Action action, Int32 retryLimit, Int32& retries) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnConnector.cs:line
>   205 at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.SvnSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 pathFilters,
>   Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2&
>   ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\SourceProviders\Subversion\SvnSourceProvider.cs:line
>   595 at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) in
>   D:\v2.0\A1_work\1\s\Tfs\Service\Build2\Extensions\BuildPollingJobExtension.cs:line
>   101.

It seems that the process that polls the subversion does not use the private build agent and is therefor unable to resolve the URL. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Base on the path (D:\v2.0\A1_work), it uses private build agent. Can you access that server from that build agent? To change the build agent: 1. Open build definition=> Process=> Default agent queue.

Comment: What if you queue the build manually? The error message seems occur when the CI build is queued.

Comment: The build works when I queue it manually, so the build server has access to the subversion server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows when VSTS server handle the triggered CI build for svn repo.

I posted this issue [VSTS CI build always failed if get sources from SVN repo](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102569/vsts-ci-build-always-failed-if-get-sources-from-sv.html), you can follow up.

It turned out the failure is caused by the svn remote can't be reached for the public network. The svn repo is setup on private repo, while the CI build requester Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS can't access to your private server.

The work round is located the svn repo to public network, so that it can be accessed by VSTS.

Comment: Is there no other workaround for CI with private SVN repositories?
Can't the Azure Pipeline call a local (private) build agent for the polling?